# Цикл с локатором

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Имею таблицу формата:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
      ...
      <td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

Для примера:

[image: пример таблица]

В цикле надо проходить каждый `row` и проверять если `col1 > 0`, то добавляем в сумму значение `col2` из этой же строки. т.е. по примеру ответ: 4

Как правильно составить такой обход ?

Думал использовать `@FindBy(css="селектор который находит все не нулевые col1")`, но не знаю как правильно это сделать

Comment: Может что-нибудь [такое](https://gist.github.com/monperrus/3761429#file-gistfile1-java-L18-L28) или [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324262/5812238) подойдёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таким образом находится список строк таблицы:

```
@FindAll({
            @FindBy(css="tr[role=\"row\"]")
    })
    private List<WebElement> tableRows = null;
```

Так выглядит функция:

```
Double focusRow(){
        double sum=0;
        for (WebElement row: tableRows ) {
            if (!(row.findElement(By
                    .cssSelector("td[col=\"col1\"]"))
                    .getText()
                    .equals("0"))
            ){
                sum += Double.parseDouble( row.findElement(By
                        .cssSelector("td[col=\"col2\"]"))
                        .getText().replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]","")
                );
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```